# How to set request attributes from jsf / javascript and retrieve from serveltFilters

Tags: ajax, jsf, servlet-filters

How to set HttpServletRequest attributes from jsf / javascript and retrieve from serveltFilters without submitting the form again .
(On a AJAX call - I am not able to see request parameters using request.getParameters in serveltFilters so I want to set them explicitely in jsf/js and send request to serveltFilters ).

Comment: Please [read this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly. Add to your question the code you tried so far, what's the expected result and what you get instead.

Comment: Especially the [mcve] part and also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info